# Did I input the correct ACWP, BCWS and BCWP values? [EVMS]

Tags: metrics, evm

[image]

I know I performed the calculations correctly but I'm not confident about the 3 values in red

Comment: Why are you not confident that Microsoft Project is not calculating correctly?

Comment: This isn't a MS project problem - just simple EVMS in excel. I'm not sure if I interpreted the problem correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [Wikipedia page for BCWP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Budgeted_cost_of_work_performed), your BCWS number is probably wrong.

Unless the project has reached its deadline date (100% of projected time used) the BCWS column would not be 100% of the projected cost.

The BCWS column would have the % of the budget based on % of time. (As opposed to the BCWP column that has the % of the budget based on % of tasks completed)

As Wikipedia shows in the example provided:

> To illustrate the difference between the three terms, assume that a schedule contains a task "Test hardware" estimated to run from 1 January to 10 January and to cost $1000, and that this is a simple effort with no overhead or allocated costs. However on 5 January, halfway through the time allowed, the work is 30% complete and has spent $250.
>
> BCWP is $1000 (budgeted cost) times 30% (work performed), or $300
>
> BCWS is $1000 (budgeted cost) times 50% (scheduled amount), or $500
>
> ACWP is $250

Answer (score 0):

Your BCWP and ACWP are correct, per the information you are providing.  It is unknown whether your BCWS is correct because "to date" is insufficient schedule information for anyone to make a determination.  If the project should have completed by "to date," then BCWS = BAC and is correct.  If "to date" means at some or any point before the scheduled finish date, then BCWS < BAC and is not correct.

To capture the correct BCWS, you need to calculate how much of the project, in dollars, should have been completed by the date you are taking a measurement.  Keep in mind that % in time is NOT the correct way of calculating BCWS because spend is not distributed evenly in most cases on a project.  That only works if your labor and material costs are literally the same value for every project work day.  There are cases when that's true but not in most.